# Prove $T:X\to X$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T:X\to X$ be linear operator. Let $A$ be s subset of $X^*$ which separates the points in $X$. Suppose $f\circ T$ is bounded $\forall f\in A$, show that $T:X\to X$ is bounded.

I think it is kind of using Uniform Boundedness theorem, but I have no idea how to do it. Could you please give me some hints please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try the closed graph theorem? Then you need to show that the conditions $x_n\to x$ and $T(x_n)\to y$ imply $T(x)=y$. Since $A$ separates points, this will follow from $f(T(x))=f(y)$ for all $f\in A$. Can you conclude?

Comment: I think that is it:

$f(T(x)=\lim f(T(x_n))=f(\lim T(x_n))=f(y)$, if $T(x) \neq y$, that will contradict the condition A separates points.

Comment: Right. That's it.